# SIFT MATLAB implementation (magnitude value)

Tags: matlab, sift

would like to know the answer to the following question regarding SIFT if anyone knows.

Before I start, I refer you to the implementation of David Lowe's paper through this link:

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/

The function declaration looks like this:

[image, descriptors, locs] = sift(img);

The variable locs return [x y scale orientation], I want to know that the "scale" is the magnitude of the keypoint (x,y) with orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh.
From the readme file of this release:

> % locs: K-by-4 matrix, in which each row has the 4 values for a
>   % keypoint location (row, column, scale, orientation).  The
>   % orientation is in the range [-PI, PI] radians.